How to update chat conversation list in real-time in a MERN app using Socket.io?
I'm working on a hierarchical MERN chat app where conversations are displayed based on user roles. I want the conversation list (chat heads) to update in real-time without requiring a page refresh.
The scenario is as follows:
If UserA initiates a conversation with UserB, this new conversation should immediately show up in UserB's sidebar.
I have Socket.io set up and can send/receive messages in real-time, but I'm struggling to make the conversation list itself update live.
Here's what I've tried:
I emit an event from the server when a new conversation is created.
On the client side, I listen for this event to update the conversation list.
However, this approach isn't working as expected—the new conversation only appears after a manual refresh.
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
import Message from "../models/message.model.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: `${process.env.SOCKET_HOST}:${process.env.SOCKET_PORT || 3000}`,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

const userSocketMap = {}; // {userId: socketId}

export const getReceiverSocketId = (receiverId) => {
    return userSocketMap[Number(receiverId)];  // Ensure receiverId is treated as a number
};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("a user connected via socket", socket.id);
    let userId = socket.handshake.query.userId;

    // Convert userId to a number if it's a valid numeric string
    userId = Number(userId);

    // Only store the user if the userId is a valid number
    if (!isNaN(userId)) {
        userSocketMap[userId] = socket.id;  // Store the userId as a number
    }

    // Emit the list of online users (numeric IDs)
    io.emit("getOnlineUsers", Object.keys(userSocketMap).map(Number));  // Emit as numbers

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("user disconnected", socket.id);
        delete userSocketMap[userId];  // Ensure userId is treated as a number
        io.emit("getOnlineUsers", Object.keys(userSocketMap).map(Number));
    });

    

    socket.on("newMessage", async ({ senderId, receiverId, message }) => {
        try {
            const newMessage = await Message.create({
                senderId: Number(senderId),
                receiverId: Number(receiverId),
                message,
            });
    
            const conversation = await Conversation.findOneAndUpdate(
                { participants: { $all: [senderId, receiverId] } },
                { $set: { lastMessageAt: new Date() } },
                { new: true, upsert: true }
            );
    
            // Increment unread count for the receiver
            const unreadCount = conversation.unreadCounts.get(receiverId.toString()) || 0;
            conversation.unreadCounts.set(receiverId.toString(), unreadCount + 1);
            await conversation.save();
    
            const senderSocketId = getReceiverSocketId(senderId);
            const receiverSocketId = getReceiverSocketId(receiverId);
    
            [senderSocketId, receiverSocketId].forEach((id) => {
                io.to(id).emit("updateSidebar", {
                    senderId: Number(senderId),
                    receiverId: Number(receiverId),
                    message: newMessage,
                    unreadCount: conversation.unreadCounts.get(receiverId.toString())
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error sending new message:", error);
        }
    });
    
    

});

export { app, io, server };


import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Conversation from './Conversation';
import { useSocketContext } from '../../context/SocketContext';
import { useAuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';
import useConversation from '../../zustand/useConversation';
import UserPopup from './UserPopup';
import { BiMessageSquareAdd } from "react-icons/bi";

const Conversations = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [groupedUsers, setGroupedUsers] = useState({});
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const { socket } = useSocketContext();
    const { authUser } = useAuthContext();
    const { selectedConversation, setSelectedConversation, messages } = useConversation();
    
    const userDetailsCache = useRef(new Map());

    // Merge user details for each conversation
    const mergeUserDetails = (conversation, usersData) => {
        let userDetails = userDetailsCache.current.get(conversation.id);
        
        if (!userDetails) {
            for (const role in usersData) {
                const user = usersData[role].find(u => u.id === conversation.id);
                if (user) {
                    userDetails = user;
                    userDetailsCache.current.set(conversation.id, user);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            ...conversation,
            fullName: userDetails?.fullName || "Unknown User",
            profilePic: userDetails?.profilePic || "/default-avatar.png",
            roleName: userDetails?.roleName || "Unknown Role",
            email: userDetails?.email,
        };
    };

    // Sort conversations based on the last message timestamp
    const sortConversations = useCallback((convs) => {
        return [...convs].sort((a, b) => new Date(b.lastMessageTimestamp || b.createdAt || 0) - new Date(a.lastMessageTimestamp || a.createdAt || 0));
    }, []);

    // Update a conversation to the top when a new message is received
    const updateConversationToTop = useCallback((conversationId, message) => {
        const numericConversationId = Number(conversationId);
    
        setConversations(prev => {
            const conversationIndex = prev.findIndex(conv => Number(conv.id) === numericConversationId);
            
            if (conversationIndex === -1) {
                console.log(`Conversation with ID ${numericConversationId} not found`);
                return prev;
            }

            const isSelected = selectedConversation?.id === numericConversationId;
            const updatedConversation = {
                ...prev[conversationIndex],
                lastMessage: message.content || "(No Content)",
                lastMessageTimestamp: message.createdAt,
                unreadMessages: isSelected ? 0 : (prev[conversationIndex].unreadMessages || 0) + 1
            };

            const otherConversations = prev.filter(conv => Number(conv.id) !== numericConversationId);
            return sortConversations([updatedConversation, ...otherConversations]);
        });
    }, [selectedConversation, sortConversations]);

    // Fetch initial data
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const [usersResponse, conversationsResponse] = await Promise.all([
                    axios.get('/api/users'),
                    axios.get('/api/conversations')
                ]);

                if (usersResponse.data) {
                    setGroupedUsers(usersResponse.data);
                    Object.values(usersResponse.data).flat().forEach(user => userDetailsCache.current.set(user.id, user));
                }

                if (conversationsResponse.data) {
                    const mergedConversations = conversationsResponse.data.map(conv => mergeUserDetails(conv, usersResponse.data));
                    setConversations(sortConversations(mergedConversations));
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data", error);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };
    
        fetchData();
    }, [sortConversations]);

    // Mark messages as read when a conversation is opened
    const markMessagesAsRead = async (conversationId) => {
        await axios.post(`/api/conversations/${conversationId}/read`);
        
        setConversations(prev =>
            prev.map(conv =>
                conv.id === conversationId ? { ...conv, unreadMessages: 0 } : conv
            )
        );
    };

    // Handle clicking on a conversation
    const handleConversationClick = async (conversation) => {
        if (conversation.unreadMessages > 0) {
            await markMessagesAsRead(conversation.id);
        }
        setSelectedConversation(conversation);
    };

    // Update conversation list on new message
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!messages || messages.length === 0) return;

        const lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];
        if (!lastMessage) return;

        const conversationId = selectedConversation?.id === lastMessage.senderId 
            ? lastMessage.senderId 
            : lastMessage.receiverId;

        updateConversationToTop(conversationId, lastMessage);
    }, [messages, updateConversationToTop, selectedConversation]);

    // Listen for new messages via Socket.IO
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!socket) return;

        socket.on("updateSidebar", ({ senderId, receiverId, message }) => {
            const targetUserId = senderId === authUser.id ? receiverId : senderId;
            updateConversationToTop(targetUserId, {
                ...message,
                content: message.content || "(No Content)",
                createdAt: message.createdAt || new Date().toISOString()
            });
        });

        return () => {
            socket.off("updateSidebar");
        };
    }, [socket, authUser.id, updateConversationToTop]);

    const startConversation = async (user) => {
        const existingConversation = conversations.find(conv => conv.id === user.id);
        
        if (!existingConversation) {
            userDetailsCache.current.set(user.id, user);
            const newConversation = {
                id: user.id,
                fullName: user.fullName,
                profilePic: user.profilePic,
                roleName: user.roleName,
                email: user.email,
                lastMessageTimestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                unreadMessages: 0,
            };

            setConversations(prev => [newConversation, ...prev]);
        }

        setSelectedConversation(user);
        setShowPopup(false);
    };

    const roles = Object.keys(groupedUsers);
    const filteredGroupedUsers = Object.fromEntries(
        roles.map(role => [
            role,
            groupedUsers[role].filter(user =>
                user.fullName?.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
                user.email?.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            )
        ])
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
            if (e.altKey && e.key === 'n') {
                e.preventDefault();
                setShowPopup(true);
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="py-1 flex flex-col overflow-auto relative ">
       <div className="flex justify-between px-6 top-2 right-2 z-10 border-b-2 border-vox-blue">
            <span className="text-sm text-vox-icons mr-2 font-bold cursor-pointer"                 
            onClick={() => setShowPopup(true)}
            >Start a New Chat</span>
            <BiMessageSquareAdd
                className="min-w-5 min-h-5 text-vox-icons cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => setShowPopup(true)}
            />
        </div>
    
        {showPopup && (
            <UserPopup
                roles={roles}
                groupedUsers={groupedUsers}
                filteredGroupedUsers={filteredGroupedUsers}
                setShowPopup={setShowPopup}
                startConversation={startConversation}
                searchTerm={searchTerm}
                setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm}
                conversations={conversations}
            />
        )}
    
        {loading ? (
            <span className="loading loading-spinner mx-auto"></span>
        ) : (
            conversations
                .filter((conv) => conv.id)
                .map((conversation, idx) => (
                    <Conversation
                        key={conversation.id}
                        conversation={conversation}
                        lastIdx={idx === conversations.length - 1}
                        unreadMessages={conversation.unreadMessages}
                        onClick={() => handleConversationClick(conversation)}
                    >
                        <div className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {conversation.roleName}
                        </div>
                    </Conversation>
                ))
        )}
    </div>
    
    );
};

export default Conversations;


How should I structure my Socket.io events to ensure that the conversation list updates in real-time?
Are there specific lifecycle methods or state management techniques that work better with Socket.io in a React/Node.js app?
